# discord.js(12) command permissions problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make my say command working only for admins but I have problems with the permissions. Here is my code:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return;

    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "say")) {
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        const SayMessage = message.content.slice(5).trim();
        message.channel.send(SayMessage);

        if (message.deletable) message.delete();
        return;
    }
});
```

It looks fine for me, the but console says this:

```
  if(!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return
                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of null
```

Comment: Was the command ran inside a Guild? (<Message>.member is undefined if the message is coming from a DM.)

Comment: If I recall correctly, `member` returns null if the message was sent in a DM. Try running this in a server

Comment: no it doesn't even work, console shows it right after starting a bot

Comment: That code is inside the message event, it will only fire when a message is sent

Answer (score 0):

I think your bot is getting dm messages from someone as soon as it starts... Try adding this:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if(message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
```

Comment: still doesn't work, maybe I should post here my full code?

Answer (score -2):

The function to check if the user has "ADMINISTRATOR" permissions is `message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")`, and you put `message.member.hasPermissions("ADMINISTRATOR")`... That's the main problem.

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "say")) {
        if (!message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return; // Is permissions.has, and you put hasPermissions
    // Rest of your code
    }
});
```

Comment: [`GuildMember.hasPermission()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission) is completely valid. That's what the OP has in his question.

Comment: In my code (hasPermissions) actually doesn't work (using v12), only works permissions.has

Comment: Because it is not hasPermission**s**, but hasPermission...

Comment: I want to say "hasPermission", sorry

Comment: OP's problem is not `hasPermission()` (which is valid in v12). The problem is that `message.member` is null.

Comment: I think that It can be message.user.member

Comment: I tried all of this solutions and they dont work. Console says undefined or null every time I try them. Maybe I should change version of discord.js and rewrite bot on v11?